# change layers during learning in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want to make an auto-encoder in Keras. Before sending the output of the encoder to the decoder, I want to add a noise image having the same size as the encoder, and after that send both to the decoder. I want to know if this is possible or not.

When this section of my code is encountered:

`merge_encoded_w=cv2.merge(encoded,w)`

I get this error:

`TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`

My entire code is below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Activation,UpSampling2D,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GaussianNoise
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from time import time
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
# Embedding phase
##encoder
w=np.random.random((1, 28,28))

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
merge_encoded_w=cv2.merge(encoded,w)
#
#decoder

x = Conv2D(2, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge_encoded_w)
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
#x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

#Extraction phase
decodedWithNois=GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)
x = Conv2D(8, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(decodedWithNois)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
#x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
final_image_watermark = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)


autoencoder = Model([input_img,w], [decoded,final_image_watermark(2)])
encoder=Model(input_img,encoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=['mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error'],metrics=['accuracy'])
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_validation, x_validation),
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])

decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_test)
encoded_imgs=encoder.predict(x_test)
```

Please help me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you want to [`stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) these tensors instead?

Comment: Or actually you just need to put the arguments to `merge` in another list, like so `merge([encoded, w])`.

Comment: I do not understand what should I do. due to I am a beginner and I am not familiar with keras and tensorflow. I want to know is it possible to change the number of filters during learning. because I want to add this w image with the same size of encoded and consider 2 filters as the output of encoded part instead one 28X28 output. is it possible or not? if yes how? do you understand what do I say? please help me.

Comment: no one can help me????!!!

Comment: You can fix the `TypeError` by changing `merge_encoded_w = cv2.merge(encoded, w)` to `merge_encoded_w = cv2.merge([encoded, w])`.

Comment: I used this but it produces this error "ipdb> TypeError: mv is not a numpy array, neither a scalar" I do not have a variable with this name"mv"?!!

Comment: Please post the full Traceback (as an edit to your question).

Comment: as  a_guest said I change this line "merge_encoded_w = cv2.merge(encoded, w)" to "merge_encoded_w = cv2.merge([encoded, w])" but it produced this error "TypeError: mv is not a numpy array, neither a scalar". I do not have any variable named mv. so I do not know what should I do now. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Seems like `cv2.merge` is not compatible with tensorflow tensors. Try to use [`tensorflow.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) instead (or [`keras.backend.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/stack) alternatively).